# Issues with creating a 30kHz soundwave in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

[image]

I want to create a 30kHz sound with MATLAB ( after which I use the Earthworks microphone ( M50 ) to test / analyse the audio replay (sound) produced from the synthetised signal stored by MATLAB in a **`.WAV`** file ).

I use the following code, but whether it is some wrong, and **if I want to create another 50kHz wave, how should I modify the code?**

```
Fs        = 96200;    
toneFreq1 = 30000; 
nSeconds  =    20;  
f1        = sin( linspace( 0, nSeconds*toneFreq1*2*pi, round( nSeconds * Fs ) ) );
sound( f1, Fs ) 
wavwrite( f1, Fs, 24, '30khz.wav' );
```

Comment: " but whether it is some wrong" is not very descriptive - please explain in detail what isn't working and how you are testing it. Human ear can't hear sounds at that frequency so I wouldn't be surprised if many speakers (esp cheap PC speakers) aren't designed to be able to play such high frequencies...

Comment: To: Dan. First i use computer to create a 30khz/40khz/50khz wav by matlab. Then i play the wav by computer and amplifier and a speaker, then i use the M50 microphone and a recorder to record the sound(from the speaker). Finally, i use a matlab program to convert the wav into a figure.Thank you.

Comment: how sure are you that your PC speakers can play such high frequencies? Also you still have not said what went wrong making this a very poor question.

Comment: TO Dan, i have check my PC speakers parameter that it can speak the high frequencies(max 48khz). When i play the 30khz wav created by matlab, and record by a recorder, then i use a program to convert the wave into a figure(above), but the high frequencies is about 18khz?

Comment: Fs =96000;    
toneFreq1 = 30000; 
nSeconds = 20;  
f1 = sin(linspace(0, nSeconds*toneFreq1*2*pi, round(nSeconds*Fs)));
sound(f1,Fs) 
wavwrite(f1, Fs, 24, '30khz.wav');

Comment: By the way, when i create a 20khz wav by matlab and play it,the figure result is right. So i don't know the problem is.

Answer (score 5):

First, most soundcards are not able to play back using your Fs. Typically, they offer 88200 or 96000 Hz, so you should choose one of them.

Second, due to [Nyquist-Shannon theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem) you can't create a frequency higher than half the sampling rate. I.e. with Fs=96000 the highest possible frequency is theoretically 48000 Hz, but then you need to use `cos` instead of `sin`.

**Update:** You are creating, playing back, recording, and analysing a sound. So, you have various sources of error.

My two points above correct your problems with creating the sound. The following matlab program shows clearly that the synthetic signal comprises exactly the sine wav you intended to create. So, the problem your original question was about, is solved:

```
clear
Fs = 96000;
toneFreq1 = 30000;   % change between 0 and Fs/2=48000
nSeconds = 20;
f1 = cos( linspace (0, nSeconds*toneFreq1*2*pi, round(nSeconds*Fs) ) );
freqz( f1, length(f1) )
```

Thus, the new spectrogram image of your modified question reflects other problems that are due to playing back, recording, and/or analysing.

It is hard to say, what problem you face. I just can give you some hints:

1) Most probable, your amplifier and/or loudspeaker are not able to reproduce frequencies much above 20kHz. You should start with frequencies between 8 and 12kHz, then you are able to hear them. If you are older than, say 40 years, it could be hard for you to hear frequencies above ca. 15kHz. But even if you are 20 years old you're not able to hear frequencies above ca. 18 to 20kHz (at least you need huge amplification to hear them).

2) Your microphone is able to convert these high frequencies into an electrical signal, but it is possible that either your microphone amplifier or your sound card is bandwidth-limited to say 22 or 24kHz.

3) Your program that converts the measured signal into a spectrogram might have bugs.

4) The segmentation at the beginning and end of the measured signal also introduces artifacts into the spectrum.

If you need further help, you should post your recording and analysis code. But I guess that with my hints you are able to find the problem on your own. Nonetheless, it would be interesting to inform us about your results.

Comment: TO: Hartmut Pfitzinger,  Thank you for your suggestion, i will try it.

Comment: TO Hartmut pfitzinger, i have tried to use cos instead of sin, and with FS=96000, but the figure(above) showed a 18Khz when i created a 30khz WAV by matlab.

Comment: @yang bin see my Update

Comment: Pfizinger, Thank you very much, I will try it.